# Iterative loop operation with IF statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have a data.frame with three rows and five columns. I want use IF statement to apply an iterative upgrade of my results until that my conditions will be achieved. More specifically, I want perform a cumulative column reduction in my dataframe. The condition is that the final dataframe will contain values in which the sum of columns be less or equal 9 (V1,V2 and V3).

I have been working on a code, however I'm with difficult to apply the cumulative iteration parameter. Until now my code is:

```
dataset<-data.frame(V1=c(2,3,4),V2=c(1,2,3),V3=c(0,1,1),V4=c(5,5,3),V5=c(7,8,9))

my.func<-function(x){
df<-data.frame(Class=colnames(x), Val = colSums(x), row.names = 1:length(x))
 if(any(df$Val>9)){
  z<-as.character(df[which.max(df$Val),1])
  w<-x[,-which(colnames(x)==z)]
  dados<-data.frame(Class=colnames(w), Val = colSums(w), row.names = 1:length(w))
if(any(dados$Val<=9)){
  h<-dados
  }
return(h)
 }
}
```

This code partially works. My problem with this lines is that the code doesn't upgrade the operation based in the last dataframe modification. Someone could help to understand where the code fail?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but as far as I can see you just want

```
dataset[names(dataset)[colSums(dataset) <= 9]]
```